# Can I subscribe to YouTube TV while traveling in the USA?

Tags: usa

I am planning to travel to the USA for a couple of months on a business visit. I do not have a USA banking account (so, no US-based credit card / debit card).

Can I buy a subscription for Youtube TV just for a couple of months after reaching the USA and connect to a WiFi? I am planning on staying in Denver for the two months I will be be in the USA. I do have an International Debit Card and a Paypal account (linked to my UK bank account).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

They don't seem to say anything about a requirement for a US-based card. You can apparently also pay via iTunes, and you can open a US iTunes account by buying iTunes gift cards in the US.

Location verification seems to be based on your Internet connection rather than your payment method, and you need to be able to connect from a location that is in one of the areas they cover.

However, if your goal is to sign up while you're over there, and then continue using the service back home, the FAQ says:

> #### Can I watch YouTube TV while traveling?
>
> YouTube TV works everywhere in the U.S., with live TV offered in areas where we’re launched. Your access to local networks will vary depending on which zip code you're in. **Sign in from home at least once every 3 months to keep your account active**. (Note, you’ll need to sign in from home monthly in order to stream MLB content.) **You won’t be able to access any programs on YouTube TV, either live or recorded, while traveling internationally.**

(emphasis mine).

So, even if you are able to sign up, you won't be able to use the service once your back in the UK.

Comment: the world is so "old-fashioned" right ?!

Comment: It all comes to IP, rights, distributors, exclusivity, etc. Once the world is dominated by Google as sole worldwide distributor of all content it will all be much easier ;->

Comment: lol really :/ ...

Comment: It's like .. remember "region! codes!" on DVDs.  So annoying.   (Remember DVDs?)